# Cannot load local fonts to my vue app via sass

Tags: vue.js, sass

Im using *sass loader* in my vue app (using vue CLI 3) for styling, yet when i try loading local fonts in one of my scss files i get the error *This relative module was not found*.
For simplicity i've put my font file in the same folder as my scss file (not in assets) and heres the code:

```
$sansFont: "notoSans";

@font-face {
  font-family: "notoSans";
  src: url("regular.ttf");
  font-style: none;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

When i search all i get is webpack, which i dont use and know about, so am i making a mistake in file positions/url or do i **have to** use additional packages to load files in my scss file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for `vue-cli 3`:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'notoSans';
    src: url('~@/assets/fonts/regular.ttf');
    font-style: none;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Inside `src: url('~@/assets/fonts/regular.ttf');` the `~@` refers your `src` path. Where you store it or what you call your folders is up to you.